# Flutter: create const color from hex string

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, constants, default-value

I am using Firebase remote config to store my color values. This gives me the flexibilty to update colors without the need to update my app. Now I have written myself a helper function which returns the color object.

In my Firebase remote config I have stored the hex color codes as strings. However, now I am facing the problem that my colors are no constants (`const`). This is a huge problem for me as I have set default color values in some constructors like here:

```
const CustomIcon(
    {required this.iconType,
    this.size,
    this.color = Helper.getColor("black"),
    Key? key})
    : super(key: key);
```

Because my color is not a `const` value anymore I get the following error: https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#non_constant_default_value

This is my helper function:

```
static Color getColor(colorName) {
  final remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance;

  String colorString = remoteConfig.getString(colorName);

  const color = Color(int.parse(colorString));

  return color;
}
```

Do you have any idea on how I can solve this problem?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sadly won't be able to const anything from the API. The `const` keyword implies that the Dart Analyzer knows what the value will be even before compiling. This isn't the case here, as the values come from the API.

However, you can still have a solution, by using a local `Color` default value, and checking for a `null` color.

```dart
class CustomIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final String iconType;
  final int? size;
  final Color? color;

  late final Color defaultColor = Helper.getColor("black");

  CustomIcon({required this.iconType, this.size, this.color, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _color = color ?? defaultColor;
    // Build your Widget
    return Container(
      color: _color,
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a simple DartPad showing it in action: https://dartpad.dev/?id=562c943972abaefd29b7b264e16ad5aa

Comment: Thanks for your workaround! But thats the point. The color does not come from the API! It comes from a config which is cached every 10 min by an API call. But I do not need to use `async` or make an API call as the color value is cached and available right away!

Comment: @Jan That's what I assumed when I posted my answer : The call to Helper.getColor() was synchronous (As you couldn't do an asynchronous call in a default parameter value anyway). However, the values still aren't known to your code beforehand, so you still won't be able to use `const` here. 

`const` values are basically validated at compilation, so any value obtained at runtime can't be `const`. I do think my workaround does achieve the same objective with as little code as possible, though!